# Some parts are not printing in output screen in my jarvis python project

Tags: python

Here is my python code

```
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def wish():
    strftime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S")
    st = datetime.date.today()
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    print(f"The time is {strftime} and Date is {st}")
    if 0 <= hour <= 12:
        speak("Good Morning")
    elif 12 <= hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon")
    elif 18 <= hour < 21:
        speak("Good Evening")
    else:
        speak("Good Night")

    speak("Hello, I am LoveAngel. Please, May I know how can I help you.")


def takecommand():
    print("process start")
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone as source:
        print("listening")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=5)

    try:
        print("recognizing")
        query = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, language='en-in')

    except Exception as e:
        speak("say again")
        return "none"
    return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    takecommand()
```

The output of my program is

```
The time is 02:51:59 and Date is 2021-03-20
Good Morning
```

As you can see some things are missing in the output screen.

missing thing
"Hello, I am LoveAngel. Please, May I know how can I help you."

Please help me this is my first big python project and i dont know what to do with it. i am trying to figure out this for almost a week but couldnt get it resolved.

Comment: Please read about [ask]. Explain ***what*** is missing from your output? What do you expect your code to do and how it differs. It is best to work out a [mre]. Sometimes in the process you will find the problem yourself